# Which is the appropriate FluentUI or Fabric package to use going forward?

Tags: reactjs, office-js

With FluentUI and Fabric merging (is there an ETA?), which packages should I be using to make the move as smooth as possible going forward?

I'm currently using "office-ui-fabric-react" > 7, which I believe is appropriate but there is a massive disparity betwen it and FluentUI (~0.46)

Comment: lol I was specifically asked by a Microsoft rep to post this question here and it gets down voted ...

Comment: Does this blog post released this morning answer your questions? [UI Fabric is evolving into Fluent UI](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/ui-fabric-is-evolving-into-fluent-ui/)

Comment: Thanks @RickKirkham, that's perfect! Great explanation for what's happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @RickKirkham in the comments, he pointed me to the new blog post on the Microsoft  Developer site

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/ui-fabric-is-evolving-into-fluent-ui/

In the FAQ is the following:

> Do I need to rename all my package imports to something new?
>
> No. Package names will stay the same as a result of the merge and rename effort. We’ll continue releasing all UI Fabric packages as we do today. We’ll also alias publish the same packages under a new name, so that at any time you can use the new @fluentui/react package with no breaking changes.